# Set Theory ZF Axioms Doubt

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, axioms

I have a pretty basic question about the symbolic representation of the axiom of extensionality for set theory, which states that

$$
\forall A \forall B [ \forall x (x\in A \iff x\in B)] \iff A = B
$$

Now, I have been reading the Enderton's *Elements of Set Theory*, and it states that the notation $\forall x$ denotes "for every set x". However, my question is: x is not really a set, is it? It should be an object, right? For example, if I have the set {1,2,3}, wouldn't it be correct if I wrote $ 1 \in \{ 1,2,3 \} $, and here $1$ is not a set, right?

Comment: As explained in the answer below, in ZF and ZFC, everything is a (pure) set. This raises the question: What set should represent $0$? $1$? $2$? $\mathbb N$? $\frac12$? $\mathbb Q$? $\pi$? $\mathbb R$? What about ordered pairs such as $(a,b)$? These are puzzles for you to think about. (Or just read on in your book.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In axiomatic set theory, we usually take the position that **everything is a set**, and in particular everything we need to care about as *elements* of a set are themselves sets.

The expectation is then that things like "$1$" are to be interpreted as abbreviations for particular sets that *represent* the numbers. A common choice of representative for the natural number $1$ is the set $\{\{\}\}$, as you will no doubt learn when you read further on in the book.

The reason why this is done is that it turns out it can be made to work (if you're willing not to worry too much about not being able put the Platonic integers into sets, but only certain other sets that represent them), and it simplifies the axioms that they don't have to deal with things that are not set. This is technically convenient.

It is *possible* to do axiomatic set theory in a way such that sets can contain things that are not themselves set -- usually those things are called *urelements*, and are assumed to have no properties (as relevant for set theory) except that they can be distinguished from each other somehow. This is not what is usually done (and is not what "ZF" or "ZFC" usually refers to), but, again, you can do it if you want to.

Comment: (+1) Just about urelements (or atoms) we commonly assume they form a set; although it is not rare to see situations where this is not assumed either.

Comment: @Henning Makholm , thank you for your answer, I got it now! Just a small doubt though, if someone asked us if 1 was a set or not, we would answer as 'yes' then, right ?

Comment: @punjabidon In ZFC, the answer is "yes." (ZFC only deals with "pure sets," such as {}, or {{},{{}}}, or {{},{{}},{{{}}},{{{{}}}},…}, or the set of subsets of that last thing. So 1 is represented by some set, usually {{}}.)

Comment: @punjabidon: That would depend on the context. If the context is that you're doing axiomatic set theory in the usual way, then yes, $1$ is certainly a set. However, if you're doing _ordinary everyday_ mathemathics, _without_ having any particular intention to formalize it in ZFC (you know you could do it if you wanted to, but you don't want to most of the time), then I hold that it is most _useful_ to deny that numbers are sets; certainly asking whether something is an element of $1$ at that everyday level of abstraction is a pretty good sign that some confused thinking is going on.

Comment: (The above comment may or may not be a majority opinion. I'm pretty sure it is how most actual mathematicians _think_ about things, but it is conceivable that a majority would _claim_ they're working within ZFC all of the time -- but this claim is most often made by people who're not set theorists anyway).

Comment: @punjabidon To add to Makholm's comment, while set theory can be used to formalize mathematics, it's not the only thing that can be used. I've heard that _type theory_ is another way to formalize it, and in type theory, $1$ is not a set. But in most set theories, such as ZFC, $1$ is a set.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: But then you formalize type theory inside set theory, and $1$ is again a set! :-P

Comment: @AsafKaragila But then you could formalize set theory inside type theory… :-P

Comment: @columbus: There are several different ways to do type theory. In Russell-Whitehead type theory, if I remember correctly, $1$ is a set, namely the set of all one-element sets of urelements. On the other hand, in Martin-Löf type theory, $1$ is a non-set, a member of the inductive type of natural numbers.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh

Comment: @HenningMakholm: In Russellian type theory you might more accurately say "each number one is a set," since there are infinitely many instances of $\mathbb{N}$, for which claims of isomorphism wouldn't even be formulae of the language.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine is right.  One of the inconveniences of Russell's type theory is that there's a separate $1$ at every type above the urelement type.  (Actually, that's the case in a simplified theory of types; Russell would also have orders, superimposed on the types, for even more complexity.)